# How to remove null data in java derby database?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, netbeans-8

I worked on how to input data into java derby database, but once I save my data into database and needs previewing my data always come up with null e.g nullFemale or nullMale. While I need only Female and Male to be displayed, how to solve this please........
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo4wL.png)

**My code is**
 [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgp5P.png)

Comment: Please don't post your table example data and your code as images. Include it directly in your question as plain (formatted) text.

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

GENDER is null. Then you modify it using

```
GENDER += male.getText() + "";
```

So you concatenate null with the actual gender.

Just don't do that. Just use

```
GENDER = male.getText()
```

There is no reason to use concatenation. And GENDER shouldn't even be an instance variable. it should be a local variable.

Notes:

- Post your code **as text** in the question. Blind people can't read your images. I can't copy-paste code from your images. People behind firewalls can't read your images. Next time, I'll simply vote to close your question, since it doesn't respect the rules.
- Respect the Java naming conventions. ALL_CAPS is for constants (static final variables). Not for variables.

Comment: Thanks #JB Nizet, I made it and it is helpful